# List row columns with different icons in css

Tags: css, html

How can I do one list of elements (ul with text) in a row and that each element has an icon or an image to its left. Here's an example: [list row columns with different icons in css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a17zQ.jpg)

My main problem is to put the images or icons. I dont know how to make it with an image or an icon different for each element (text) too.

Comment: I imagine that they have used FontAwesome or a similar icon font and have actually included the icon in the `<li>` content rather than as an actual list icon. See the first example here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can either include the icon/image in the list element:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="icon1.png" alt="icon" /> Text next to icon</li>
  <li><img src="icon2.png" alt="icon" /> Text next to icon</li>
</ul>
```

...or if you're using an icon font like FontAwesome then you can just do:

```
<ul>
  <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Text next to icon</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-apple"></i> Text next to icon</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try with a multiple options to align imgs with text and no one works. one of my options is that
`code`
<div class="texto">
     <div class="imagenTitulo"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40" alt=""></div>
     <div class="titulo"><h4>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h4></div>
     
    </div>
`code`
but the css is too complex. Its seems your solutions works, using vertical align to middle

Comment: Yeah, sorry I iniciate in stackoverflow. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

I can agree with Lauri. But this is how you can achive your goal without frameworks by **pure css**.

```
<style>
    ul {
        padding: 0;
    }

    li {
        padding: 0.15em 0 0.5em 1.5em;
        margin-bottom: 0.2em;
        text-indent: 0.4em;
        font-weight: bold;
        list-style: none;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 10px;
        background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_DztL2nlERHrDWBFIyA5dp9sblqn6zt57uoRB4IbAbymgpFskfg");
    }
</style>

<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, Its works, A question "text indent" could to substitute itself by margin-right